# Organizing inventory by alphabetical order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

So I created a method to populate the inventory system I have created in Unity, however I can't seem to figure out a way to order them in alphabetical order. Each button is created as a child of the button holder panel which is a game object variable. This method is called whenever the player picks something up.

```
private void Populate_Inventory ( )
{
    Button btn_CurrentItem;

    int int_Count;

    for ( int_Count = int_PreviousCount; int_Count < strList_Inventory.Count; int_Count++ )
    {
        btn_CurrentItem = Instantiate ( btn_Item, pnl_ButtonHolder.transform );
        btn_CurrentItem.name = strList_Inventory [ int_Count ];
        btn_CurrentItem.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ( ).text = strList_Inventory [ int_Count ];
        btn_CurrentItem.gameObject.AddComponent<Inventory_Item> ( );
        btn_CurrentItem.GetComponent<Inventory_Item> ( ).str_Name = cls_Pickup.str_PickupName;
        btn_CurrentItem.GetComponent<Inventory_Item> ( ).str_Information = cls_Pickup.str_PickupInformation;

        int_PreviousCount = int_Count;
    }

    int_PreviousCount++;
}
```

If anyone can help it would be very appreciated.

Jonathan Palmer

Comment: Isn't this as simple as sorting the strList_Inventory before running the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue with this approach is that you're adding single buttons at a time whenever you pick up an item, and those buttons are created as children of the `pnl_ButtonHolder` object, but your method has no knowledge of previous buttons that have been created.

### Option 1 (Bad)

You can use the `GetComponentsInChildren<Button>()` method on the `pnl_ButtonHolder` object to get all of the button components that have been previously created once you've added a new button, and then sort your buttons according to their name.

This isn't ideal as `GetComponentsInChildren<>()` is an expensive method, and doesn't make use of the idea of an Inventory very well.

### Option 2 (Good)

Create an `Inventory` class that manages your actual inventory, including sorting items. It might look something like this:

```
public class Inventory_Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button button = default;

    public void Initialize(Intenvory_Item item)
    {
        button.name = item.name;
        // Other work here.
    }
}

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject inventoryItemPrefab = default;
    public Transform inventoryParent = default;

    private List<Inventory_Item> _inventory = new List<Inventory_Item>();
    private List<Inventory_Button> _inventoryButtons = new List<Inventory_Button>();

    public void AddItem(Intenvory_Item item)
    {
        _inventory.Add(item);
        Inventory_Button button = GameObject.Instantiate(inventoryItemPrefab, inventoryParent).GetComponent<Inventory_Button>();
        button.Initialize(item);
        _inventoryButtons.Add(button);
        _inventoryButtons.Sort((x, y) => x.name.CompareTo(y.name));
    }

    public void RemoveItem(Inventory_Item item)
    {
        // Do work to remove the item.
    }
}
```

This kind of setup is useful for several reasons:

1. Your inventory management is now handled by a single class rather than a collection of objects. This makes it easy to interact with.
2. It will make removing items much easier in the future. With your current implementation, it looks like you'd have a difficult time removing an item from the player's inventory.
3. It separates responsibility between an `Inventory` class, an `Inventory_Item` class, and an `Inventory_Button` class, each of which stands on its own and works together.

A few final notes:

- I've left out some details in the two classes above. You should fill them in to fit the needs of your game.
- You can be more efficient with sorting by using something like [Insertion Sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/). This solution will get the job done.
- Using prefixes for naming your variables can be quite confusing to people trying to read your code. I recommend you check out a style guide. There's a great one [here](https://github.com/raywenderlich/c-sharp-style-guide).